# Allowing blank records despite validation

Tags: ms-access, vba

Many of my database forms use a listbox with 4 columns and several textbox/combobox controls which are mapped to their respective fields using the ‘control source’ in the property sheet.

I validate these using ‘`If Trim(control.value & vbnullstring) = vbnullstring then`’ and then ask the user to enter their ID number in a textbox (also mapped using control source) if the controls are not null.

An issue was raised with my database last night where a user managed to enter a record into the database with just their user number (my time field also contained an entry as its set to `default = Now()`) but every other field was blank.

The code below is what I’ve been using to prevent accidental blank records:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Not blnSave Then
    Cancel = True
    Me.Undo
 End If
End Sub
```

Then my `Submit_Click()` button event contains this to save the record…

```
blnSave = True
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
blnSave = False
```

I can’t recreate the problem myself as my validation won’t allow you to even enable the ‘User ID’ control until something is selected in the listbox and all textboxes contain a value. What could have caused this? Would it be better to add records to the table using a query rather than relying on the Control Source property or am I focusing on the wrong thing?

Comment: If DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec fails, blnSave will still be True.

Comment: @Gustav Would it stop the blank entry if I set the blnSave back to false using `On Error goto X` or something?

Comment: Yes, if it really does fail - it was just an idea for a possible source of error.

Comment: basic validations should be set table level. like if a field can be null or not. Check a secondary validation in submit button and then use the command accmdSaveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user circumvented your form by accessing the database table directly? Could that be possible?

Comment: We use these Wyse computer things & citrix reciever that stop you opening the backend/Access in design mode. I can only do that on my laptop.